# Image Processing: Segment characters, projection?

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing

I am facing a problem in segmenting characters from a license plate image.

I have applied following method to extract license plate characters, after this I will input every character into a OCR (tesseract):

1. Rgb2gray.
2. Canny edge detection and dilation.
3. Mark and filter areas.
4. Extract a single characters image.

The results are attached below:

[image]

On the first column work well.

At the second column there is a Chinese plate, and it is difficult to correctly identify every character.

At the third column there is another plate, which it was rotated through the hough transform because it was from another angle, however, it cannot detect any character.

I'm [working here, on Google Colab.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p5Fvip6sdyV-qkpwDMXFZLYeVc64vQFP?usp=sharing)

What can I improve? any advice?

These are the image im working [at this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I0aDv8BoqmZvWXgjD3xlThTzUaLlWDXs)

I think the problem it maybe at Canny edge detection:

```
img3 = feature.canny(img2, sigma=3)
img4 = morphology.dilation(img3)
```

Or filtering areas:

```
label_img = measure.label(img4)
regions = measure.regionprops(label_img)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

def in_bboxes(bbox, bboxes):
    for bb in bboxes:
        minr0, minc0, maxr0, maxc0 = bb
        minr1, minc1, maxr1, maxc1 = bbox
        if minr1 >= minr0 and maxr1 <= maxr0 and minc1 >= minc0 and maxc1 <= maxc0:
            return True
    return False

bboxes = []
for props in regions:
    y0, x0 = props.centroid
    minr, minc, maxr, maxc = props.bbox

    if maxc - minc > img4.shape[1] / 7 or maxr - minr < img4.shape[0] / 3:
        continue

    bbox = [minr, minc, maxr, maxc]
    if in_bboxes(bbox, bboxes):
        continue

    if abs(y0 - img4.shape[0] / 2) > img4.shape[0] / 4:
        continue

    bboxes.append(bbox)

    bx = (minc, maxc, maxc, minc, minc)
    by = (minr, minr, maxr, maxr, minr)
    ax.plot(bx, by, '-r', linewidth=2)
```

For apply projection before steps.

Comment: You must make the image deskew before extract a single characters image. You can use the Hough or Radon-like transform to find the skew angle.

Comment: Hough it is for straighten the image, right? Because I use Hough for that in the last column

Comment: @Sebastián maybe Alex means that you have to find the skew angle through going from cartesian space to Hough, or Radon [space](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/470/whats-the-difference-between-the-hough-and-radon-transforms), that's different from Hough line transform, the line transform is just one application of that space.